# How to slide a div from left to right in a Jquery Mobile page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to slide div from left to right on button click in a Jquery mobile page .

What exactly I want is to push that current div to left and reveal another div with content like some menu from right .

I have created a **JSfiddle** . Here is the [**Updated Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/vLvXF/2/)

So if you see in the fiddle each list div has a `gear` button so when you click this button it should push only that div to left and reveal another div fro right showing some menu .

I have a hand drawn sketch that I am including in this

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div id="clock" data-role="header" style=" background:skyblue;">
            <h1>List View</h1>

    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
    <div role="main" class="ui-content" style=" background:orange;">
        <div class="fieldset" id="myform1">List 1 <a class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-gear" value="SUBMIT" id="sub2"></a>

        </div>
        <div class="fieldset" id="myform2">List 2 <a class="ui-shadow ui-btn  ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-gear" value="SUBMIT" id="sub1"></a>

        </div>
        <div class="fieldset" id="myform3">List 3 <a class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-gear" value="SUBMIT" id="sub0"></a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>

    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#sub2").click(function () {
        // alert("This is an alert");
        $('#myform1').toggle('slide', {
            direction: 'right'
        }, 700);
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the jQuery.animate() documentation.. http://api.jquery.com/animate/ i think that is what you're looking for.

Comment: I didn't see anything about the new div to show in your fiddle. Here's my [fork of it, for what it's worth](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/WuN6X/1/).

Comment: @MarkRijsmus thanks bro yes I am looking into it . But can i do this using any of the Jquery mobile features . Maybe a panel could be modified like this ???

Comment: @AustinMullins thanks for the idea . Okay I am going to update my fiddle with the new div .

Comment: @Vikram Sorry, i can't help you with that.. I'm not a mobile specialist. :)

Comment: @MarkRijsmus I tried the concept you introduced here . the nearest I could get is this  http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/vLvXF/2/

Comment: @Vikram: I have tried something [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vLvXF/11/). It might not be the exact solution you are looking for, but you could get something to move on.

Comment: @Rohith  Thanx Mate :) . Even I was working on it here is my fiddle but Mine has a problem . i.e "The first list works fine but the 2nd and third List I have to click the button twice idk why its happening would you like to look into it?? " http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/vLvXF/10/

Comment: Add `class : rightSlide` to every `div` with `class : fieldset`. Updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLvXF/12/)

Comment: @Rohith Oh yeah! I forgot to add it yes right thanks btw your solution is much better than mine but Its not working properly Althuogh I like your script more actually. Anyways bro there is one more thing missing that is when I click list1/2/3 then any other list has to go back to its older position if its opened have any Idea how I should do it ?

Comment: Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLvXF/17/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57301/discussion-between-vikram-and-rohith).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solve my own problem with the help of comments provided by others . Here is the solution.

Although there is little bit change i.e I changed the `div` to `li` that's all

**SCRIPT**

```
$(".fieldset a").click(function () {
    //var ul_parent= $('li.fieldset').parent();

//$(ul_parent).find('li').each(function(){ //code here });

     $('li.fieldset').each(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('rightSlide')) {
        }else{
             var form = '#'+$(this).attr('id');
             var arr = form.split('_');
             var menu = '#menu_' + arr[1];
             var theClass = form;
            console.log("The opened id : "+form);
            toggle(form,menu,theClass);

     }
     });

    var form = '#'+$(this).closest('li').attr('id');
    var arr = form.split('_');
    var menu = '#menu_' + arr[1];
    var theClass = form;
    toggle(form,menu,theClass);
   // console.log(menu);


    function toggle(form,menu,theClass){
    if ($(theClass).hasClass('rightSlide')) {
        $(form).animate({
            "margin-left": "-200px",
                "margin-right": "200px"
        }, "slow").removeClass('rightSlide');
        $(menu).animate({
            "margin-right": "0px"
        }, "slow");
    } else {
        $(form).animate({
            "margin-left": "0px",
                "margin-right": "0px"
        }, "slow").addClass('rightSlide');
        $(menu).animate({
            "margin-right": "-200px"
        }, "slow");

    }
    }

    //$('.hidenset').toggle(400);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div id="clock" data-role="header" style=" background:skyblue;">
            <h1>List View</h1>

    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
    <div role="main" class="ui-content" style=" background:orange;">
        <ul>
            <li class="fieldset rightSlide" id="myform_1">List 1 <a class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-gear" value="SUBMIT" id="sub2"></a>

            </li>
            <li class="hidenset" id="menu_1">Menu 1</li>
            <li class="fieldset rightSlide" id="myform_2">List 2 <a class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-gear" value="SUBMIT" id="sub2"></a>

            </li>
            <li class="hidenset" id="menu_2">Menu 2</li>
            <li class="fieldset rightSlide" id="myform_3">List 3 <a class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-gear" value="SUBMIT" id="sub2"></a>

            </li>
            <li class="hidenset" id="menu_3">Menu 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>

    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fieldset {
    height:100px;
    background:green;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom: 2px !important;
    margin-top: 2px !important;
    color:white;
}
.hidenset {
    background:red;
    margin-top: -103px !important;
    width:180px;
    height:100px;
    margin-bottom: 2px !important;
    margin-right: -200px;
    color:white;
    /*display:none;*/
    float:right;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.fieldset a {
    float:right;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    height: 21px !important;
    width: 21px !important;
    padding-right: 20px !important;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
}
```

The [**UPDATED LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/vLvXF/19/) for JS FIddle